# Flutter - audioplayers-audiocache

Tags: аудио, flutter, dart

Задача такая:
нужно чтобы при включении приложения, начинала играть музыка, выключалась автоматически при переходе.

```
  class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: SafeArea(
            left: false,
            right: false,
            bottom: false,
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(image: ImageApp().imageWelcome, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                FadeAnimatedTextKit(
                  text: [
                    TextApp().textWelcome1,
                    TextApp().textWelcome2,
                    TextApp().textWelcome3,
                    TextApp().textWelcome4,
                    TextApp().textWelcome5,
                    TextApp().textWelcome6,
                    TextApp().textWelcome7,
                  ],
                  textStyle: TextWelcome,
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Это кусок кода из приложения. В

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
```

будет добавлен переход на другой экран. Музыка будет браться из assets. Просьба помочь с кодом. Можно просто пример накиданный Вами, в свое приложение я уже добавлю сам. А то и прежде возникали проблемы с audioplayers, хотелось бы сделать все правильно без костылей, которые будут изобретаться мной.
Благодарю

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers/example

Answer (score 1):

Советую использовать https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers. Там в примере есть то что надо. Остановить проигрывание можно в dispose.